# Azure Keyvault get values based on environment

Tags: c#, azure

I'm using Azure Keyvault to get the application configuration values. I'm able to read the values and view in the application.

Code:

```
<add key="ClientId"          value="="************************" />
<add key="ClientSecret"      value="************************" />
<add key="AddressURI"        value="https://Example-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/Address1"/>
<add key="SupportEmailURI"   value="https://Example-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/SupportEmail1"/>
<add key="MarketingEmailURI" value="https://Example-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/MarketingEmail1"/>
```

I have 3 environments: Development, Stage and Production.

Now in `web.config`, if I am moving the application to deploy in different environments, I need to manually change the endpoint of Azure Keyvault as I am using different subscription for each environment.

Is there a way where we can set the environment end point dynamically in C#?

**Endpoint** = "https://Example-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/MarketingEmail1"

This value need to be changed based on the environment?

```
Example-keyvault.vault.azure.net
```

Any insights on how to get this done will be great !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the application settings of the app service, instead of the having the key vault URL in the web.config. That way you won't have to take care of managing the key vault URI based on the environment, you just have to set it once in the app settings in every environment as shown below. You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common)
[image]

I would also suggest you to consider using  [Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) (if you are not doing already) You can either enable a system-assigned Managed identity or go for a user assigned managed identity for your app service and give necessary permissions to the app services' identify to the key vault. You can enable the Managed Identity from your App Service in Azure Portal as show below
[image]

The advantage of having managed identities is that you can workaround the bootstrap problem associated with Azure Key Vault. You may find [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/keep-credentials-out-of-code-introducing-azure-ad-managed-service-identity/) article helpful.

Comment: The problem with the application settings of the app service is any one who have access to App service can view the value straight away.

Comment: Hi @KumarRaj,  yes, the setting will be visible for anyone with appropriate privilege to your app service but you will only have the URL for the KeyVault and not any secrets there. With managed identities you don't need your  KeyVault's access key anywhere in the settings.